# How to convert a list of arrays in a single array when arrays have different shapes in python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list of arrays of different dimension and i want to concatenate those arrays into one single array.

suppose i have

```
LIST = [array([[0.786, 0.819]]), array([[0.811, 0.804]]), array([[0.821]])]
```

and i want to convert it in an array:

```
ARRAY = array([0.786, 0.819, 0.811, 0.804, 0.821])
```

so I would like to concatenate all the values of each arrays of my list in a single array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [numpy.hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) and no need for looping

```
import numpy as np

LIST = [np.array([[0.786, 0.819]]), np.array([[0.811, 0.804]]), np.array([[0.821]])]

arr = np.hstack([*LIST])
arr
array([[0.786, 0.819, 0.811, 0.804, 0.821]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
np.hstack([i[0] for i in LIST])
```

It could be `np.hstack(LIST)`, if your arrays were vectors and not matrices, i.e. using only a single `[]`, instead of `[[]]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [np.array([[0.786, 0.819]]), np.array([[0.811, 0.804]]), np.array([[0.821]])]
a = np.array([])
for x in l:
  a = np.concatenate((a, x[0]))
print (a)
```

Outuput

```
[0.786 0.819 0.811 0.804 0.821]
```